# Is it possible to add SetInterval inside Extendscript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, extendscript

is it possible to add a setinterval() javascript inside extendscript? I want the script to keep running while photoshop is being used, yet I'm not sure if this is possible or not, if not I will have to find another solution to what I am trying to do..

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: A casual google led me to several posts on the Adobe forum as well as [a replacement code](http://armand.eu/blog/setinterval-for-adobe-extendscript/)

Comment: @Jongware - If that answer can't be found on SO, feel free to add it yourself. `;)`

Comment: This is trickier than it seems.  Not all Adobe products that support ExtendScript have a app.idleTasks object